# Application toolbar on the left in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Using Eclipse RCP to build an application. I would like the toolbar to be vertical and on the left hand side of the window. So far I managed to make it vertical in the ApplicationActionBarAdvisor.

```
@Override
protected void fillCoolBar(ICoolBarManager coolBar) {
    ToolBarManager toolbar = new ToolBarManager(coolBar.getStyle()
                                                    | SWT.HORIZONTAL);
    coolBar.add(toolbar);
}
```

However, it is still on top of the editors and view. I cannot find any way to move it to the left. Does anybody know if it is possible at all and how to do that?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension point o.e.ui.menu, and use the locationURIs "toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.vertical1" for left trim and "toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.vertical2" for the right trim. You can your tool items there.

Also see the contribution examples plugin for more samples: http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions/